# When trying to load JSON file directly to my rails database (Rails.root, 'lib', 'file.json'), rails says 'invalid access mode'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, shared-libraries

Here's a sample of the code, which I'm trying to load from rails c (inside the lib folder--the file data2.json is also inside of the lib directory)

```
$LOAD_PATH.unshift(File.expand_path(".", File.dirname(__FILE__)))
$LOAD_PATH.unshift(File.expand_path("./lib", File.dirname(__FILE__)))

require 'company_gem_class'

class LoadJson

  def go
   File.open(Rails.root, 'lib', 'file.json') do |f|
      f.each_line do |line|
        this_line = JSON.parse(line)
        hash_parser = CompanyGemClass.new(line)
        c = Company.new
        c.followers = hash_parser.followers
        c.company_name = hash_parser.company_name
        c.date_joined = hash_parser.date_joined
        ...
        c.save
      end
    end
 ...
 end
```

The plan was/is to load all this raw data through a single (Company) class directly from the rails console. I've been getting lots of "json file does not exist" (Ennooent::path/to/file.json does not exist).

I've tried putting it in the lib/assets folder and lib folders, but no success yet. How might I go about this task of mass-uploading these json-->ruby objects to the db?

^^I've already bundle-installed the json gem.
^^The json files are one hash per line, so that's why I did it like this

Comment: You didn't copy the code from my answer correctly. Read point 3 again. You need to call `File.join`.

Comment: Ok..looks like you got it now..great :)

Comment: Indeed I did because of the true lord which is stack overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I'm sure you know (however it was not completely obvious from your question) that `File.open` does not use `LOAD_PATH` for anything. So no matter what you put in `LOAD_PATH`, it will not affect how `File.open` works. `LOAD_PATH` only modifies how `require` searches for files.
2. In Rails all your file operations should use `Rails.root` as the base path. You cannot rely on your current working directory to be something specific when working with Rails.

   So any `LOAD_PATH` modifications should be done with something like this:

   ```
   $LOAD_PATH.unshift(File.join(Rails.root, 'my', 'uber', 'lib'))
   ```
3. Because of (1) and (2) - If you're going to open any file with `File.open` the most reliable way to do it is using `Rails.root`:

   ```
   File.open(File.join(Rails.root, 'path', 'to', 'file.json'))
   ```

   Or in your case:

   ```
   File.open(File.join(Rails.root, 'lib', 'assets', 'file.json'))
   ```
4. In Rails `lib` is already in your `LOAD_PATH` by default. So you do not need to add it separately.

Comment: Rails isn't liking me trying to access the 'lib' folder et al., I started out with "ArgumentError: invalid access mode lib" when putting in the "Rails.root, 'lib', 'file.json'". Even with "Rails.root, lib" it throws ArgumentError: invalid access mode lib before it is able to complain that I'm calling a directory...so accessing the 'lib' folder in this way is not looking like it's going to work. Trying "Rails.root, 'file.json'" doesn't work either. Same error for that, too. So maybe its not the lib in particular that it doesn't like. Rails.root returns '/path/to/rails_app is a directory'

Comment: @putin2012 - Well where exactly did you put the file named `file.json`? What's the path to that file?

Comment: rails_app/lib/file.json. Earlier I had put it in the lib/assets folder but just moved it to the lib folder after these errors starting coming up

Comment: Excellent! On to the next one. Thanks.